# How to convert ANSI colored text to PDF

Tags: pdf, ansi

I have a program that generates console output colored with ANSI codes.  How to convert it to PDF keeping the colours?

I need a unixish command line solution

Comment: Found something close to what I need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html

and then print HTML as it is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176476/how-can-i-automate-html-to-pdf-conversions

Answer (score 5):

The best solution so far: `aha` to convert to HTML (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html), then convert HTML to PDF e.g. with `wkhtmltopdf`.

I am still looking for a one step solution.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [script](https://github.com/markrages/ansi_svg) that does ANSI->SVG.  You can then convert to pdf with headless Inkscape.

Example:

`ls --color | ./ansi_svg.py | inkscape -z -f /dev/stdin --export-pdf=ls.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

If you have [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)/[pdfcreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/)/cutepdf kind of utility installed in your environment or computer. You can use lp to send text to printer.

Comment: Thank you, but they all are GUI stuff, and pdfcreator is Windows only.  Don't fit.